# Обновление навигационного свойства в EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Добрый вечер.
Подскажите, пожалуйста. Имеется модель данных в EF в которой реализована связь один ко многим. Создание элементов непосредственно в базе происходит в штатном режиме. Однако, при редактировании элемента возникает сложность. Если меняется скалярное свойство, то обновление происходит корректно. Если же дополнительно меняется навигационное свойство, то скалярная часть при обновлении изменяется корректно, а навигационная не меняется.
В принципе, я это решил на чистом T-SQL, однако, хотелось бы понять как такая задача должна быть реализована средствами EF.

Comment: Опишите Вашу проблему более подробно. Приведите упрощённые примеры кода, демонстрирующие вашу проблему, а то так сложно понять что и где Вы изменяете и что у вас не так.

Answer (score 1):

Объект, которым вы пытаетесь заменить текущее навигационное, должен существовать в контексте. Иначе у Вас ничего не получиться.